# Advice on how to shape data for lstm

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, regression, lstm

I have a time series of 933 matrices, each matrix is a 8x10 matrix. This is my X (input). So X has shape (933, 8, 10).
The Y (output) is a time series of 933 vectors, each vector is a 5-dimensional vector. So Y has shape (933, 1, 5).

I can also reshape the data (should I?) such as X is (933, 80) and Y is (933, 5) because really in the end it is just 933 samples of a set of 80 numbers for input (imagine 80 pixels in a matrix) and 933 samples of a set of 5 numbers for output.

I am writing a CNN-LSTM. I still don't know the size of train/test, let's assume for now that I want to use all 933 samples for training. My model is:

```
model = Sequential()
# define CNN model
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(1, (2,2), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(None,8,10))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
# define LSTM model
model.add(LSTM(933, activation='relu', input_shape=(8,10)))       
model.add(Dense(5))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(X, Y)
```

I get the following error:
ValueError: input tensor must have rank 4.

My question is why I am getting this error and how could I solve this?

Comment: For time series prediction with LSTMs, you need to shape your data in a particular way. Check [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/) out.

Comment: Please update the question, I will be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

For LSTM, the input must be `3D` that is `(samples, time steps, features)`.
In your case, you need to reshape your data to `(933,8,10)`

In the LSTM layer, the argument `input_shape` takes a tuple of two values that defines the number of `time steps` and `features`.
In your case, it would be `(8,10)`

And the number of units for an LSTM layer you can mention any, usually it will be 32,64 or 128 range. Having too many units will not help the model to learn.

Below is the sample LSTM layer for your data.

```
data.shape= (933,8,10) 

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(8, 10)))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(X, Y)
```